# Checking a dictionary with while loops Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary, while-loop, format

I am trying to write a code where it would run try to filter out `dict A` and check if the filteration fails or if the `result` value is equal to `None`, then I want the while loop to re-run, however the output of the code shows that it only runs once? How would I be able to fix that?

```
A = ({})
while True:
        try:
            updatedCandle = A["result"]
            if updatedCandle is not None:
                print("break")
                break
            
        except: 
            print('\nRETRY\n') 
            A = ({'ret_code': 0, 'ret_msg': 'OK', 'ext_code': '', 'ext_info': '', 'result': None, 'time_now': '1624576211.927034'})
            print(A["result"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop does **not** run once. In fact, it runs **indefinitely**.

`A["result"]` causes a `KeyError` in the first iteration and returns `None` for every subsequent iteration, so the `break` is never executed.

For debugging purposes, add

```
else:
    print('keeps running')
```

to the `try` block, and you will see it being printed infinitely.